# Should the amounts in W-2 Box 14 appear in Box 14 in TurboTax?

Tags: united-states, form-w-2, rsu, turbotax, form-1040x

I bought some company stock via ESPP and had my first bundle of RSUs vest. The amounts are both shown in box 14 of my W-2.

However, I don't see any value imported into box 14 of my 1040 tax return document within TurboTax.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I edited your question because there's no such thing as "box 14" on a 1040, so I assumed you meant something called "box 14" within TurboTax's presentation of your 1040.  But I know nothing about TurboTax, so feel free to revert my edit if my assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These amounts should appear in the W2 as imported by Turbo Tax. You should be able to go to the "Income" section, and check the W2 as imported there. It should match. If it doesn't - correct it.

ESPP-related entry on box 14 in W2 doesn't appear on your 1040 as is, instead it affects the calculations on your Schedule D. It should appear as adjustment to basis for the corresponding sales of the ESPP shares.